# How to induce R to "ignore" NAs when indexing into a dataframe?

Tags: r

I've got a dataframe that contains some NAs and when I index into it I would like R to ignore the NAs in that column.

```
fake = data.frame(id = 1:5,
                  color = c('red', NA, NA, 'blue', 'blue'),
                  value = rnorm(5))

sub = fake[fake$color != 'red', ]

     id color      value
NA   NA  <NA>         NA
NA.1 NA  <NA>         NA
4     4  blue -0.3227421
5     5  blue -1.0196561
```

The dataframe I want back is:

```
  id color      value
2  2  <NA>  0.2761862
3  3  <NA>  1.0029380
4  4  blue -0.3227421
5  5  blue -1.0196561
```

But for whatever reason, R NAs out the entire row when an NA in 'color' is encountered.  I've tooled around with 'na.exclude,' 'na.pass,' etc., but haven't found a clean way to do this.

Comment: The title of your question seems opposed to the content. You do not want R to "ignore" NA's so much as recognize and include rows with NA in you selection column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
fake[!fake$color %in% "red",]
#   id color      value
# 2  2  <NA> -1.1341590
# 3  3  <NA> -0.6181337
# 4  4  blue  0.6115878
# 5  5  blue  1.3984797
```

Comment: Was just about to post this solution.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it is better to use `setdiff` in this case:

```
fake[setdiff(rownames(fake), which(fake$color == "red")), ]
#   id color     value
# 2  2  <NA>  1.015132
# 3  3  <NA> -1.425210
# 4  4  blue  1.089207
# 5  5  blue  1.442323
```

Comment: FWIW, the reason were seeing that result was due to the result of your subset logic:  `fake$color != 'red'`.  Since `NA` is not comparable, you get those two rows.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting tripped up by `!=` returning NA rather than TRUE. This should succeed:

```
  sub = fake[ is.na(fake$color) | fake$color != 'red', ]
```

Nothing equals `==`, NA and furthermore nothing is not-equal `!=`, to NA, *not* even NA. Notice:

```
> is.na(fake$color) | fake$color != 'red'
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

> NA == NA
[1] NA
```

But the NA's can give you what you want when combinied using OR ,`|`

```
>  NA | TRUE
[1] TRUE
```